# Extract callstack of all threads of a single process - volatility

Tags: system-calls, dump, callstack, volatility

is there any way to use volatility in order to extract the callstack of all threads of a single process given a PID? By extracting the callstack I intend to view all the system calls currently stacked.

Thanks.